# Bınding global function with "this" affects only one instance of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a form builder system. I have a global function named `setLabel` which is binded to a component named `InputBox` and changes its state. This global function is triggered via another component named `ModalPanel` which controls the editable properties on the binded component `InputBox`. I have simplified the function and component class for simplicity of this question;

Here is the global function;

```
function setLabel(postID, attributeName ){

    var text = 'example';
    if(text !== ''){

    this.setState({ [attributeName] : text});

    }
}
```

And here is the component which is binded to the `setLabel` function. Notice that, how `setLabel` function is passed from parent `InputBox`component to child `ModalPanel` component function as a property.;

```
class InputBox extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder : '',
            maxlength: '',
            type: '',
        }

        this.setLabel = setLabel.bind(this); // Binding this to the global function.
    }

render(){

        let elementId = "inputElement-" + this.props.idCounter;
        let mainElement = <Form.Control id =  {elementId} type={this.state.type}
                                        placeholder = {this.state.placeholder} 
                                        maxLength = {this.state.maxlength}
                            />
        return  <Row>
                <ModalPanel handleHide = {this.props.handleHide} handleShow = {this.props.handleShow}  setLabel = {this.setLabel}/> 
                </Row>
    }
}
```

Lastly, below is the `ModalPanel` component function where the `setLabel` function is triggered.

```
function ModalPanel(props){

return(
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................
<Button variant="primary" onClick = {() => props.setLabel()}>Save changes</Button>
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................)
}
```

`setLabel` function which is aimed to set the state of `InputBox` must be triggered when a button is clicked in the `ModalPanel` component. The problem is, there are rendered multiple `<InputBox />` components on the window and when I try to use this functionality, "the state change" only affect the first instance of `<InputBox />` component. What I want to do is that, every instance should have their own internal state and `setLabel()` function should be binded to the spesific component from where it is called. So that, this function can be able to set the state of different component instances. How could I do that?

Thanks.

**Addition:**

Please check the link below to see a gif how my system works wrong. As you can see, even though I choose the third input box element to edit its properties(in this case, set its placeholder text), the change is being made on the first one;

[Go to gif](https://gfycat.com/crispunfortunatechicken)

Comment: This is definitely not an issue with global function binding. Please see sample based on your code (https://codesandbox.io/s/so57050376-bwkmf) It works correctly. So it may be issue with correct props passing or similar.

Comment: How could I identify the issue in this position? My code's logic is very similar to your example but they work differently.

Comment: It seems that you pass incorrect prop to some component. E.g. use `.map(p => (<InputBox prop1={'prop1'}/>))` So passed some constant in place of value. Or similar

Comment: Can the problem be about `handleHide()` and `handleShow()` functions which are binded to the main component where `InputBox` components are instanced in and these functions passed as props to `InputBox` instances?

Comment: After I make my controls, It looks like I am passing all of the props correctly but I am still suspicious on setLabel function itself.

Comment: @Fyodor, I really can't identify the problem, my code looks pretty much same with yours and I double checked all of the property flow.

Comment: Please, share all your code, if possible in some sandbox

Comment: @Fyodor, Here is the whole project, you can produce the same problem; https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-murdock-y8qch